# Post checkins on your facebook wall giving error

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook-graph-api

I m using this code. Actually I want to do is, On my wall I get a map `checkins` that I was here.

```
 private void getFb()
  {
    fb = new Facebook(Constants.facebookKey);
    String[] arrayOfString = new String[2];
      arrayOfString[0] = "publish_stream";
      arrayOfString[1] = "me/checkins";
      fb.authorize(this, arrayOfString, new FBDialogListener());
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
  {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }


  private class FBDialogListener implements Facebook.DialogListener
  {

        public void onComplete(Bundle values)
        {

             Bundle params = new Bundle();
             params.putString("place", "MyPlaceId");  // YOUR PLACE ID
             params.putString("Message","I m here in this place");

             JSONObject coordinates = new JSONObject();
             try {
                coordinates.put("latitude",Constants.latitude); // The place Coordinates
                 coordinates.put("longitude", Constants.longitude);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             params.putString("coordinates",coordinates.toString());

             JSONArray frnd_data=new JSONArray();
             fb.dialog(MainMenu.this,"me/checkins", params, new PublishDialogListener());


        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {

        }

        public void onError(DialogError e) {    

        }

        public void onCancel() {

        }
  }

  private class PublishDialogListener implements Facebook.DialogListener
  {

        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {

        }

        public void onError(DialogError e) {


        }

        public void onCancel() {
        }

  }
```

This just gives me error on

```
The page you have request is not found.
```

What is wrong?
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no `me/checkins` permission, so this is wrong:

   ```
   arrayOfString[1] = "me/checkins";
   ```

   You instead [need the `publish_checkins` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#checkins). So change it to:

   ```
   arrayOfString[1] = "publish_checkins";
   ```
2. The [`Facebook.dialog()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/dialog/) method is for opening predefined dialogs, such as the *post status* or *authorize an app* dialog. You instead want to make a custom request directly to the Graph API. This can be done using the [`Facebook.request()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/request/) method like this:

   ```
   String jsonResponse = fb.request("me/checkins", params, "POST");
   ```

Side note: The Facebook SDK also provides a convenience method for [submitting requests asynchronously](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ayncrequest/).

Comment: I have already figured out me/checkins problem. Already fixed it but I have used fb.request, it never does anything. Can you edit my whole code and show me what should I do? I have been wasting time since 3 days ...

Comment: What are you getting as response from the request() method?

Comment: {id":"xxxxxxxx"} Actually I have a place, I want users to when they click button,on their fb wall the checkin comes that they were on that place. I have page id and coordinates of that place too.

Comment: So your code works, the call succeeds and you get a checkin id back, as documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#checkins). What exactly does not work now?